# Group by list of dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript

Input =

```
[{id: 13, display_name: "Customizable Desk (Aluminium, Black)", quantity: 4, unit_price: "800.40", discount: 0, price: "3201.60"},
{id: 40, display_name: "Magnetic Board", quantity: 2, unit_price: "1.98", discount: 0, price: "3.96"},
{id: 40, display_name: "Magnetic Board", quantity: 1, unit_price: "1.98", discount: 0, price: "1.98"},
{id: 40, display_name: "Magnetic Board", quantity: 1, unit_price: "1.98", discount: 0, price: "1.98"}]
```

Output =

```
[{id: 13, display_name: "Customizable Desk (Aluminium, Black)", quantity: 4, unit_price: "800.40", discount: 0, price: "3201.60"},
{id: 40, display_name: "Magnetic Board", quantity: 4, unit_price: "1.98", discount: 0, price: "7.92"}]
```

I am able to achieve an answer but my process is very lengthy, I need a short answer for it using some predefined functions of javascript.

Comment: please post the code as well,one you have written `the lengthy way`

Comment: It makes a **big** difference whether one can or cannot assume that `quantity` is the only thing that can be different for each item with the same `id` value or not.

Comment: @kshetline, needs to grouby dicts using `id`. `quantity` can be different.

Comment: By "grouby" do you mean "group by"?

Comment: Yess @kshetline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short way to do this (based on the assumption I cited before that `quantity` is the only thing that can vary for each item with the same `id` value):

```
inputArray.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (result.map.has(item.id)) {
    result.map.get(item.id).quantity += item.quantity;
  } else {
   result.array.push(item);
   result.map.set(item.id, item);
  }
  return result;
}, {map: new Map(), array: []}).array
```

This uses the array [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function, if you're not familiar with that. This could be done without the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but that makes it more efficient than searching through the whole result array to find `id` values which have already been seen.

The idea behind this code is that you keep the first item you see that has an `id` that you haven't seen before, and if you have seen an `id` before, you look up that original item, and add the new quantity to the previous quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
function groupProducts( input ) {
   var productsById = input.reduce( function( current, item ) {
       if( !current[ item.id ] ) {
          current[ item.id ] = [];
       }
       current[ item.id ].push( item );
       return current;
   }, {} );

   return Object.keys( productsById ).map( function( id ) {
       productsById[ id ].reduce( function( current, item ) {
           if( current ) {
              // this could be extracted as a closure passed in to coalesce items together.  Your rules for how that happens go here.
              current.quantity += item.quantity;
              current.price += item.price;
              return current;
           } else {
              return Object.assign( {}, item );  // shallow copy beware
           }
       }, null );
   } );
}
```

PS I noticed in your input sample things like quantity and price were strings instead of numbers.  I'm going to assume you know how to straighten those things out so the data has proper data types.  This won't work if you have strings for those.